# CentOS 7 tweaking sshd config to access the machine no matter how busy its

Tags: centos, configuration, memory, limit

When CentOS 7 free memory goes below 200 MB, it become unresponsive even to ssh connection.

Currently I have many machines not accessible remotely in peak time due to free memory being between 80 MB to 110 MB.

```
# free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7745        7520          98           2         126          59
Swap:          7935        7935           0
```

How to keep CentOS 7 responsive to new ssh logins even when its under heavy load?

**in other words**: if by tweaking sshd config I can access the machine no matter how busy its, then please share you insight.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is about how much free memory you have and not about how much swap you are using?

Comment: yes, even if free swap is 2 - 5 GB, I still face the same issue. based on my findings its related to RAM.

Comment: If you prevent the system using its last 200MB, how is that different from just physically removing that memory? By extension, why is that different from adding 400MB memory and still blocking the last 200MB? By final extension how is that different from what you have now?

Comment: My point being that you presumably don't really want to block the last 200MB memory, but rather you want to reserve it for some as-yet unspecified purpose. Which is...?

Comment: @roaima your point is valid, my purpose is to keep the machine responsive (being able to perform remote ssh over 4G network in peak time), I checked many times, once RAM above 200 MB I can ssh normally, in other words, it might be possible to tweak sshd config so that its always accessible even when the OS under heavy processing, if that's make sense please share your input.

Comment: @roaima edit performed.

Comment: There are a few things you can do.  Easy to find on the internet if you google really quick.  Flush your Page Caches, inodes & dentries using `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` then flush your file system buffers using `sync`.  You need root priviliedges.

Comment: @roaima full edit of the question being made, please check. and thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Renice 'sshd' to -9 and reserve the memory it needs, then it should let you in as soon as it notices you trying to connect.

Comment: @Mioriin I checked sshd config and didn't find any params can be set to -9! please share your complete answer.

Comment: Add `Nice=-9` to the `[Service]` section of `sshd.service` to renice it to -9. I'm not putting it as a proper answer since it's probably not the best idea to try to fix your problem like that.